# Skype repository key expired?

Tags: apt, gpg, skype

When I apt-get update, the repository for Microsoft's Skype says:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. 
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid:
EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease   
The following signatures were invalid: 
EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my system? And what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you need to re-obtain the GPG key, like so:

```
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -
```

and the warning/error will go away.

See [discussion of this issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/o4swyi/the_following_signatures_were_invalid_expkeysig/) on the [Linux Mint Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/).